# Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating a dropdown component in my application, but I'm getting the following error: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("

```
ncaught Error: Template parse errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let item of {{lista}}" >
      <a href="#paper">{{item.id}}</a>
    </li>
"): ng:///AppModule/PfDropdownComponent.html@12:8
Can't bind to '*ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'li'. ("
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let item of {{lista}}" >
      <a href="#paper">{{item.id}}</a>
    </li>
```

Component:

```
@Input() lista = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
    { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
    { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
    { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
    { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
    { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
  ]
```

html:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li *ngFor="let item of {{lista}}" >
      <a href="#paper">{{item.id}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why are you using `{{}}` in ngFor?

Comment: remove {{}} from lista . it will solve your *ngFor error. ``let item of lista`` is 
 the correct way

Comment: Where did you read about this syntax?

Comment: did using {{lista}} because my component will get a list.

Comment: <pf-dropdown items="{{lista}}"></pf-dropdown>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this :

use `<li *ngFor="let item of lista">` instead of `<li *ngFor="let item of {{lista}}">`

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li *ngFor="let item of lista">
      <a href="#paper">{{item.id}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I did using {{lista}} because my component will get a list.

Comment: `pf-dropdown` means primeface ?

Comment: And a component I'm creating myself.